# Python - py2exe - DeprecationWarning

Tags: python, py2exe

I've installed python 2.6 and new version of py2exe.

hello.py

```
print "Hello from py2exe"
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    # The first three parameters are not required, if at least a
    # 'version' is given, then a versioninfo resource is built from
    # them and added to the executables.
    version = "0.5.0",
    description = "py2exe sample script",
    name = "py2exe samples",

    # targets to build
    windows = ["test_wx.py"],
    console = ["hello.py"],
    )
```

and I've tried this in console

```
python setup.py install
```

but I get this error message

```
D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py:16: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
import sets
running install
running build
running install_egg_info
Removing D:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\py2exe_samples-0.5.0-py2.6.egg-info
Writing D:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\py2exe_samples-0.5.0-py2.6.egg-info
```

What did I wrong? how can I fix it?

Comment: 1. Why do you do `python setup.py install` when you want to build an EXE file? 2. What's wrong with the warning - the sets module *is* deprecated as it was replaced by the builtin `set` and `frozenset` types. Seems like py2exe is still using it somewhere.

Comment: yes, off course! you are right, i jusst type wrong command, i have to use `python setup.py py2exe`

Comment: can you write e more expressive title please? For future searches, you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not an error, its just a warning about a deprecated class; in this case the `sets` module is deprecated and the new code should use built-in `set` class now.

Comment: No it didnt! I've updated my warning/werror message, take a look.

Comment: @Meloun, there is still no error. Run `python setup.py py2exe` to build your application.